Select preseleccionado
tengo un select con ese id:
<select class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="_despacho">
     <option value="2">Kilos</option>
     <option value="1">Litros</option>
</select>

contexto:
previamente ser hace un registro, y se registra si es kilos o litros, posteriormente  se consulta la informacion, y esta se preecarga la informacion, esto sucede conla siguiente function:
function informacion(x) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Clienxxxte/xxx?xxx=' + x,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (lts_informacion) {
      

           
            if (lts_informacion[0]._tipo == 1) {
            // Si es 1 (Litros), poner Litros primero y luego Kilos
            _despacho.innerHTML = `
                <option value="1">Litros</option>
                <option value="2">Kilos</option>
            `;
            }
            else {
             // Si es 2 (Kilos), poner Kilos primero y luego Litros
            _despacho.innerHTML = `
                <option value="2">Kilos</option>
                <option value="1">Litros</option>
            `;
            }                     

        })
}

estoy devolviendo una lista con informacion y entre esos lts_editar_cliente[0]._tipo que me devuelve el value con el que se registro, la intencion es cambiar el order de las opciones, es decir: si se registro con litros que aparezca como primera opcion litros y despues kilos, y en casoi contrario, primero kilos y despues litros.
agregue algo de codigo para poder hacer eso, pero no funciona, ya que consulto y obtengo un 1, sin embargo no hace el ajuste en el select.
como puedo resolver esto?

¿Has probado a poner document.querySelector("_despacho")? Teóricamente no hace falta, pero por si acaso. También, ¿es _tipo o _tipo_despacho? En el código pone _tipo pero en el texto de la pregunta pone _tipo_despacho.

es _tipo, ya lo edite, la funcion me devuelve 1, pero sigeu sin  acomodar el select , sigue saliendo primero kilos...

¿Puedes compartir el valor de lts_informacion?

es un array contiene mas datos, pero solo necesito validar esa propiedad, y como resultado obtengo un 1

Lo comprendo, quita los valores que no sean importantes y comparte solo el array de objetos con _tipo. La idea es poder ver la estructura del elemento devuelto para poder confirmar que el código es correcto

Agregar console.log(lts_informacion[0]._tipo) antes del if, si da 1 tu error está en otro lado

Usa el atributo selected.
En esta parte:
 if (lts_informacion[0]._tipo == 1) {
        // Si es 1 (Litros), poner Litros primero y luego Kilos
        _despacho.innerHTML = `
            <option value="1" selected>Litros</option>
            <option value="2">Kilos</option>
        `;
        }
        else {
         // Si es 2 (Kilos), poner Kilos primero y luego Litros
        _despacho.innerHTML = `
            <option value="2" selected>Kilos</option>
            <option value="1">Litros</option>
        `;
        }                     

Te dejo la documentación acá: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#selected

Si selected no está presente, el elemento seleccionado es el primero por defecto.
